# Page content does not update

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Basically I'm using an API that in its response contains a variable referring to the next page and I'm trying to make all the content of the response be stored in a variable, this content is rendered and then a call is made to the API for the next page

```
export default function testComponent() {
    let data
    let page = 0
    let next = null
    const [content, setContent] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchContent = async () => {
            try {
              while(page < 5) {
                const result = await getPage(next);
                next = result.pagination.cursor

                await result.data.map((item) => {
                    data.push(item)
                })

                page++;
                setContent(data);
              }
              
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error:', error);
            }
          };
      
          console.log("useEffect trigger")
          fetchContent();
    }, []);


    if (content === null) {
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../Components/Images/bg.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.2}}>
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator color='#FFF'/>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }

    return(
        <ImageBackground source={require('../../Components/Images/bg.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.2}}>
          <View>
              <ScrollView>
                  {data.map(item => {
                    return <PageItem item={item} key={item.id}/>
                  })}
              </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    )
}
```

But only the first 2 pages are updated, I already checked and the API is returning the pages correctly, if I use a console.log(data) I can also verify that the contents returned by the API are being added to the date

Refresh the page content every time you get a response from the API

Comment: use state to render the data instead a normal variable, fetch data without loop as setState is asynchronous will only update UI after render cycle complete.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to declare variable like that because it will make a new variable every re-render. So in your code when the `content` updates, `React` makes a new `data`, `page`, `next` every single time. So when you keep your states, you always want to use `useState`,`useRef` etc, or you lose your previous states.

In this case, I assume you don't need to re-render when `next` has changed?
So it would be doing something like this...

```js
export default function testComponent() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const pageRef = useRef(0)
  const nextRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchContent = async () => {
      try {
        while (pageRef.current < 5) {
          const result = await getPage(nextRef.current);
          nextRef.current = result.pagination.cursor;

          await result.data.map((item) => {
            data.push(item);
          });

          pageRef.current++;
          setContent(data);
          setData(data)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    };

    console.log("useEffect trigger");
    fetchContent();
  }, []);
...
```

I think you can get the concept from the code.